# Was Hagar part of Abraham's punishment?

Tags: abraham, parashat-lech-lecha, egypt

The Ramban chastised Abraham for going to Egypt to escape a famine in the Holy Land and for lying about Sarah:

> And you should know that our father Abraham committed a great sin unintentionally, when he brought his righteous wife to stumble into sin because of his fear of getting killed.  He should have trusted God to have saved him, his wife and all that was his... God would [also] have saved him from dying in the famine. And because of this deed it was decreed that his seed would be in exile in Egypt under the hand of Pharaoh. [Ramban on Genesis 12:10]

Abraham then has a child by his Egyptian servant Hagar, at the urging of Sarah.  The Midrash says Hagar was Pharaoh's daughter:

> Rabbi Shim’on bar Yohai said Hagar was Pharaoh's daughter. When [Pharaoh] saw [God’s] deeds on behalf of Sarah in his house, he took his daughter and gave her to him, saying, “better that my daughter by a maidservant in this house than a mistress in another house.” [Gen. R. 45:4]

Putting the two together, could we conclude that God delayed Sarah's conceiving Isaac so that Sarah should urge Abraham to have Hagar bear a child, Ishmael, who would later become the progenitor of the Muslims, who became (and still are) enemies of the Jews, as part of his punishment for the two sins mentioned by Ramban (another part being slavery in Egypt)?

Is this point raised anywhere in the Sources?